# PostgreSQL: VACCUM FULL vs pg_dump and restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Does pg_dump do the same thing as VACCUM FULL?
I wan to clean a database at night but VACCUM FULL takes too much time. Does pg_dump also clear database form unwanted data?

Comment: "Does pg_dump also clear database form unwanted data?" No, it creates a backup file. If you make a backup and a restore your database will be cleared. But you have to stop all applications that access the database during the operation. VACCUM does it with the database online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you create a new database and restore the dump, the effect of both operations would be pretty much the same.

The big question is why you think you need such extreme measures. Normally autovacuum should take care of dead tuples, and if you have a table on which you perform bulk updates or deletes, you might consider using `VACUUM (FULL)` on that table only.

Comment: I have a performance problem in my app. High IO usage from writer process. I have not other idea what can be a problem.

Comment: You should analyze your performance problem (or pay someone to do it for you). Unless you have excessive bloat, reorganizing the database won't do much for you.

Comment: Do the disk usage savings from this process apply for individual tables that are dumped and restored as well? Or do you need to dump and restore the entire database to get the same effect as VACUUM FULL?

Comment: The database is pretty much the sum of the tables and indexes.