# Does a Postgres pg_restore restructure the table in any significant way?

Tags: postgresql

We've noticed that, when we take a pg_dump of a table, the restored table performs much better than the original. We haven't been able to figure out why.

Note that we vaccuum regularly, meaning the original table has been vacuumed. And so I don't think that's the cause of the difference.

Does anyone know what happens during a pg restore? Are the table rows maybe being re-ordered (as happens during a cluster)?

We're using Postgres 9.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: VACCUM FULL vs pg\_dump and restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951416/postgresql-vaccum-full-vs-pg-dump-and-restore)

Comment: Not a dup. As mentioned in the original post, we vacuum regularly. And so that doesn't account for the diff.

Comment: Did you read the answerd answer from the link i've provided?  "Assuming that you create a new database and restore the dump, the effect of both operations would be pretty much the **same.**" .. Besides you can setup **auto** vaccuum or setup **FULL** vaccuum  which do you use.. And what are you doing with your table is it a table with alot of writes or a table with alot or reads or is het mixed..

Comment: Yes, I read the answer. Don't see how it relates to my question. Actually, sorry. My mistake. Misread the answer from the linked question. That could be it. If a restore is doing a vacuum full, then that would explain the difference.

Comment: Don't use PostgreSQL 9.3. As to your question, please provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow and the fast query. `pg_restore` doesn't optimize the table any more than `VACUUM (FULL)` does.